# How to calculate number of pixels in a TIFF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing

I have three TIFFs that are grayscaled. There is only one pixel value, but two very clear different "colors" (majority of pixels are black, some are white). How do I separate these pixels into different classes so that I can count how many are white and how many are black so I know their ratio? Preferably in ArccGIS if possible, but I also have access to ERDAS Imagine. When I open up its attribute table in ArcGIS, it says all of the pixels have the same value, but I want to change that so the white pixels have a different value from the black pixels. I am very new to this.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine what is going on is that the white pixels are NoData and the black pixels are the single value you are seeing in the VAT. You can right click on the raster in the TOC and select properties from the drop down menu. The the resulting box go to the "source" tab. This will have information on the raster, including Columns and Rows counts. Just multiple the two and subtract the count of the single value and that will tell you how many NoData pixels you have.

Keep in mind that this assumes a rectangular extent and not irregular but, given your data there is now other way to treat the data. If you need to assign a value to NoData use [SetNull](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm)

Comment: It still isn't working. I found a problem - if I just open the tiff in an image viewer, it is just a black screen. But if I open it in ArcGIS or ERDAS it shows the correct pixel colors. So when I created the tiff in Google Earth Engine and then saved it, it must not have differentiated between the different classes?

Comment: That is not a problem, you simply cannot look at a geotif in an image viewer, the headers are not something the software can understand so, it does not display correctly. If the attribute table in ArcMAP is only showing a single value than anything else (white pixels) is nodata. As I previously stated, if you want the nodata to have a value then you need to set it to the desired value using SetNull.